# What happens when you melt a solid in a perfectly enclosed space?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Here are the parameters:

- You have a perfectly airtight box made of a very resistant material.
- You have a block of a substance that melts normally (such as aluminium) that fits perfectly in the box.

Since liquids are less dense than their solid counterparts but a liquid cannot be compressed, what would happen if you were to place the solid in the box, closed it and then attempted to melt it by increasing the temperature?

I am assuming the box is strong enough to withstand the pressure, won't react with the melting cube and also won't melt itself.

Comment: In your question, you just left out which parameters (pressure, temperature) you want to change to try to melt it. One could infer from the last paragraph that it’s pressure you want to change, but your intentions aren’t clear as the words are all we have to go off of.

Comment: Good point, I meant increasing the temperature but I never specified, I'll edit it to make it be more clear.

Comment: Assuming a crystalline solid, IMO, since you said it melted, that means it's now liquid. Normally, water aside, for example, I think this means the the ions no longer assume an ordered lattice configuration, as there's been enough heat to allow the particles to escape this periodic confinement---they wander.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since liquids are less dense than their solid counterparts but a liquid cannot be compressed, what would happen if you were to place the solid in the box, closed it and then attempted to melt it?

Liquids are not always less dense than their solid counterparts.

Liquids can be compressed, though it takes a lot of pressure to change their volume appreciably.

> What happens when you melt a solid in a perfectly enclosed space?

It probably won't melt at the same temperature as it would if it were free to expand. However, at some temperature it will lose its solidity.

By losing its solidity, I do not mean that it will necessarily "melt" in the usual sense of the term. Above the critical temperature of a substance, there is no clear distinction between liquid and gas. The material is just said to be "fluid". Consider the material in the interior of the Sun. It is often described as a "gas", but I don't think that is quite correct. However, regardless of being held at a fixed density, at some high enough temperature a material will become "fluid".

Below is a phase diagram that has temperature and density as axes.

[image]
Credit: [sklogwiki](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Phase_diagrams:_Density-temperature_plane)

Essentially, what has been asked is what happens to a substance when the temperature is raised, but the density stays the same. Vertical lines on the graph represent different temperatures with a constant density. As can be seen, the boundary between fluid/liquid and crystaline solid has a positive but finite slope. Although the graph does not extend vertically indefinitely, if the slope were to continue in the same direction, every constant density line would eventually intersect it.

Comment: Citation needed for *"Above the critical point of a substance, there is no clear distinction between solid and liquid."* The critical point usually refers the end of the liquid–gas coexistence curve on the phase diagram, so without further clarification, this part of your answer looks like a typo or misunderstanding.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Oops. Meant to write that above the critical temperature there is no clear distinction between liquid and gas.Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Well now I really don't understand your answer, as the question seems to about the solid–liquid coexistence curve, which extends past the critical point.

Comment: Yes, the question is about boundary of the solid state. Whether what lies above it is "liquid" or "fluid" depends upon whether one considers dense fluids above the critical temperature to be "liquids". Commonly, the center of the Sun is described as a gas, although it is many times denser than iron. I think "fluid" is a better term, but yes, one can say "solid/liquid" boundary if one wants.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer with this excellent diagram! It does clarify that the answer rests on whether the line at the top right generally continues to extend with a finite positive slope. “Melting” seems like a fine term, as the new fluid phase would presumably still nucleate adjacent to the solid phase at a fixed equilibrium temperature.

Comment: [This broader-scope temperature–density diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Temperature-density-phasediagram.png) is also fascinating and couples with your reference to the Sun. [This document](https://comphys.unibas.ch/TEACH/StatPhys/PhaseTransitions.pdf) discusses universal shapes of coexistence lines plotted on suitably normalized axes.

Comment: I specified in the question that the material of choice melted and froze in a regular fashion so I am assuming that the liquid would be less dense, as for liquids being able to compress at very high temperatures, I did not know that but just how high are we speaking? I imagine of course it depends on the material but a few estimations would be very helpful. Other than that the answer answers my question, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It stays solid.

Simply check with the phase diagram of your solid. To melt it, you likely would increase temperature. The density should decrease, but your box doesn't expand, so the pressure increases and you remain solid:

[image: Example Phase Diagram, from Wikipedia]

(Following the discussion, it is fair to qualify this that it stays solid until at some point it may turn into a plasma, at some huge temperature.)

Comment: I'm not sure the answer "It will stay solid" is correct. The center of the Sun is many times more dense than, say iron. However it is a fluid (often it is called a gas, but being above the critical point, I think "fluid" is more correct). Would a lump of iron, at its density under 1 atmosphere, remain solid in the center of the Sun? At 15 million Kelvins?

Comment: I think it might be better to show several phase diagrams of familiar materials to emphasize how the leftward “hook” in the liquid phase of water is unusual, as this directly pertains to the question.

Comment: @Chemomechanics, good point, thanks - fixed.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy:  There's probably some temperature at which it *would* melt, but it would be higher than the "normal" melting point of the substance.  You could even estimate the change in the melting point using the [Clausius-Clapeyron equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius–Clapeyron_relation)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The equation you linked is derived under the condition of constant pressure, not constant volume.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy... hmmm... at the center of the Sun the temperature is so high that the material turns into a plasma. So it is neither a solid nor a liquid; it is a different aggregate state. Electrons have so much energy that they are no longer bound to the nuclei, so the entire assumptions that are built in when e.g. calculating solids as periodic neutral lattices don't apply. But OK, to be picky, I added that caveat.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This answers my question well enough (I was just asking out of curiosity so it's fine if the answer doesn't work under core-of-the-sun conditions) the graph really helps visualise it. Thank you!